# Appending Tuples to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to join (vertically) some of the tuples, better to say I am inserting these tuples in the dataframe. But unable to do so till now. Problem arises since I am trying to add them horizentally and not vertically.

```
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(columns=("A","B","C","D"))
str1 = "Doodles are the logo-incorporating works of art that Google regularly features on its homepage. They began in 1998 with a stick figure by Google co-founders Larry Page and Sergey Brin -- to indicate they were attending the Burning Man festival. Since then the doodles have become works of art -- some of them high-tech and complex -- created by a team of doodlers. Stay tuned here for more of this year's doodles"

aa = str1.split()
bb = zip(aa[0:4])

data_frame.append(bb,ignore_index=True,verify_integrity=False)
```

Is it possible or do I have to iterate over each word in tuple to use **insert**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this

```
In [8]: index=list('ABCD')

In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=index)

In [11]: df.append(Series(aa[0:4],index=index),ignore_index=True)
Out[11]: 
         A    B    C                   D
0  Doodles  are  the  logo-incorporating
```

alternatively if you have many of these rows that you are going to append, just
create a list, then `DataFame(list_of_series)` at the end

```
In [13]: DataFrame([ aa[0:4], aa[5:8] ],columns=list('ABCD'))
Out[13]: 
         A    B     C                   D
0  Doodles  are   the  logo-incorporating
1       of  art  that                None
```

Comment: ha! @LonelySoul, this should work with tuples as well; is there a reason you want tuples rather than strings?

Comment: i take it all back then! :)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff . unfortunately I have too many columns so the second option will work but might have to iterate several times.

Comment: 2nd option is many times faster too, and the more 'recommended' way; appending must keep copying

Comment: index is a really misleading name here