# Appending tuples returned by for loop

Tags: python, list, sqlalchemy, tuples, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running some SQL queries using sqlalchemy. I have a for loop that runs queries against Snowflake tables.

Current Code:

```
for x in list:
    results = cursor.execute(f"SELECT TABLE_NAME as TABLE_NAME, 'TABLE_SCHEMA as TABLE_SCHEMA, MAX(DATE) as DATE  FROM {database}.{schema}.{table}")
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

This for loop returns a tuple with each iteration, like below:

```
('SCHEMA_1','TABLE_1','DATE_1')
('SCHEMA_2','TABLE_2','DATE_2')
('SCHEMA_3','TABLE_3','DATE_3')
```

etc.

How can I create a tuple of tuples from this from loop? So I can then later pass it into a DataFrame.

All I want to do is create a dataframe from the loop that will append the results each time, so I can then write the complete df back to Snowflake.

**I cannot use the snowflake-connector-python[pandas] module and need to do it with sqlalchemy + pandas.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending Tuples to Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243846/appending-tuples-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: create a list before your loop, then append to it each iteration? What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the old `cursor.execute()`, but does it return a tuple already? What is the output of `print(results)`?

Comment: @quamrana right, probably just `results = cursor.execute(...)` then just `data = list(results)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Tried doing that, if I replace print(results) with list.append(result) I just get a 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: If I do data = list(results) I just get a: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Yes cursor_execute() returns tuples

Comment: So you already have your tuple of tuples?

Comment: With each loop a tuple is returned, I need all the tuples joined together.

Comment: So how is `results` not already `"all the tuples joined together"`?

Comment: I said **use a list** not a tuple. Tuple objects are immutable. You don't need a tuple of tuples, you can just use a list of tuples, but if you really want you can convert your list to a tuple

Comment: You are getting the error about list objects not being callable because you assigned a list object to the variable `list`. Don't do that.

Comment: @quamrana with each iteration one tuples is returned, so for one loop there is one tuple returned. I am failing in putting them together, wether thats a list or tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what the list iteration is here since you don't seem to use `x` anywhere, so have omitted that.

Just append the tuples into a list:

```
data = []

results = cursor.execute(f"SELECT TABLE_NAME as TABLE_NAME, 'TABLE_SCHEMA as TABLE_SCHEMA, MAX(DATE) as DATE  FROM {database}.{schema}.{table}")
for result in results:
    data.append(result)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["schema_name", "table_name", "max_date"])
```